# MySQL data truncation Exception when uploading excel sheet

Tags: mysql, excel, exception, upload, truncation

I'm doing a task of uploading several excel sheets into MySQL in java using Eclipse, and i am using CLOB (LONGTEXT)
when i  try to execute the insert command its giving

Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'data' at row 1

but file is of only 10KB, and i came to know CLOB is encoding and collation sensitive,
I don't know how to configure character encoding settings, please tell me what i need to do to overcome this problem also please suggest me if i am supposed to be doing in any other better way.
and FYI i need to handle excel sheets which may shoot up to few MB's in size.

Thanks

Comment: You will need to show a sample of the data that breaks, and ideally the exact table structure you're importing into

Comment: Hi Pekka, thank u for your reply. Initially i gave it a try for reading text file for which i got the above said error, Now i am trying to read excel sheet using APACHE POI, i need to save the contents as it is into database without any modification and again  query the database to fetch the contents. and i have written a sample code to read the file containing only string, now i think i have to consider all the characteristics of the xlsx like cell border, cell color, cell type and other attributes of xlsx. please tell me if my understanding is wrong, can u suggest me how to approach this ?